# Multiple columns within the same SQL query

Tags: sql

I have been working on this problem for a while now and I can't figure out what to do.

I have a huge SQL query with multiple joins and it gives me hundreds of thousands of records, which is perfect.

I then realized that I had 200 odd some records in another table that needs to be added to the first.

First table:

```
Field1             Field2   Field3
john smith         23       Boston
Mohammed Ali       45       New York
Stephanie Johnson  15       Los Angeles
```

New Table

```
Field1        OtherField1    OtherField2
Mark Khoury   Null           null
```

So I really only need to add the Field1 values from table two to the "bottom" of the first. All of the joins I made in the first query should also work for the values found in table two.

A union won't work because I only have on column to add. I would have to copy-paste the same query from the first table to get "Field2" and Field3" from the values of the second.

What I want it to look like is:

```
Field1             Field2   Field3
John Smith         23       Boston
Mohammed Ali       45       New York
Stephanie Johnson  15       Los Angeles
Mark Khoury        65       Houston
```

How can I go about doing this? I don't want to "JOIN" the tables, I want to unite them but only with one column.

Here is an example of what I mean:

Table one was created by doing something like the following:

```sql
SELECT table.value1 as Field1, table2.value2 as Field2, table3.value3 as Field3 
FROM some_table as table
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_other_table as Table2 ON table.field = table2.field5
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_third_table as table3 ON table2.field2 = table3.field4
```

but now I have newTable with more Field1 values and I need to add those values to the first table.

I tried this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(table.value1, NewTable.value) as Field1, table2.value2 as Field2,
table3.value3 as Field3               
FROM some_table as table
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_other_table as Table2 ON table.field = table2.field5
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_third_table as table3 ON table2.field2 = table3.field4, newTable
```

but this is giving me an exponential amount of results, where it should be giving me a few hundred more.

Comment: UNION is how you would add more records to the bottom.  Can you please provide some sample SQL so that we can show you how to make it work?

Comment: What **datatypes** are the fields?

Comment: @christiandev it is text

Comment: If the answers already given don't help, you should include example data from table and newtable. Then give an example of what the final result would be.

Comment: @JayGee does that clarify?

Comment: It clarifies it a little bit, but on the Mark Khoury row in the desired result, where does 65 and Houston come from?

Comment: @seekerOfKnowledge it would come from the same JOINs that were used to create the First Table. Essentially, NewTable should have been part of some_table but was left out for some unknown reason. I want to treat it as if it did come from some_table.

Comment: I'm just going to make assumptions on column names and go from there. Update to my answer coming soon.

Comment: @moalaz Is my answer what you need now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a union with the first column and set the other columns as '' something like,

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Field1, '' AS Field2 
FROM table2
```

Would that get you what you needed?

Taking your example, would the below get you what you need?

```
SELECT table.value1 as Field1, table2.value2 as Field2, table3.value3 as Field3 
FROM 
    (SELECT t.value1 as Field1 FROM some_table as t
     UNION
     SELECT t2.value1 as Field1 FROM some_table2 as t2) as table
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_other_table as Table2 ON table.field1 = table2.field5
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_third_table as table3 ON table2.field2 = table3.field4
```

Comment: But I actually need the values for Field2 and Field3 which are found by using the sql query used to create the first table.

Comment: I believe that this is what I am looking for! I am trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same idea as @rhollyer, here is a script that may produce what you're asking for.

```
DECLARE @Person TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    DisplayName nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @PersonDetail TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    Age int
)

DECLARE @PersonGeoInfo TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    City nvarchar(200)
)

DECLARE @LostPersons TABLE
(
    LostPersonID int,
    DisplayName nvarchar(50),
    Irrelevant1 decimal,
    Irrelevant2 bit
)

INSERT INTO @Person (PersonID, DisplayName)
VALUES 
    (1, 'John Smith'),
    (2, 'Mohammed Ali'),
    (3, 'Stephanie Johnson')

INSERT INTO @PersonDetail(PersonID, Age)
VALUES
    (1, 23),
    (2, 45),
    (3, 15),
    (4, 65)

INSERT INTO @PersonGeoInfo(PersonID, City)
VALUES
    (1, 'Boston'),
    (2, 'New York'),
    (3, 'Los Angeles'),
    (4, 'Houston')

INSERT INTO @LostPersons(LostPersonID, DisplayName, Irrelevant1, Irrelevant2)
VALUES
    (4, 'Mark Khoury', 9.5, 1)

    DECLARE @Person TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    DisplayName nvarchar(50)
)

DECLARE @PersonDetail TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    Age int
)

DECLARE @PersonGeoInfo TABLE
(
    PersonID int,
    City nvarchar(200)
)

DECLARE @LostPersons TABLE
(
    LostPersonID int,
    DisplayName nvarchar(50),
    Irrelevant1 decimal,
    Irrelevant2 bit
)

INSERT INTO @Person (PersonID, DisplayName)
VALUES 
    (1, 'John Smith'),
    (2, 'Mohammed Ali'),
    (3, 'Stephanie Johnson')

INSERT INTO @PersonDetail(PersonID, Age)
VALUES
    (1, 23),
    (2, 45),
    (3, 15),
    (4, 65)

INSERT INTO @PersonGeoInfo(PersonID, City)
VALUES
    (1, 'Boston'),
    (2, 'New York'),
    (3, 'Los Angeles'),
    (4, 'Houston')

INSERT INTO @LostPersons(LostPersonID, DisplayName, Irrelevant1, Irrelevant2)
VALUES
    (4, 'Mark Khoury', 9.5, 1)

SELECT P.DisplayName AS Field1, PD.Age AS Field2, PGI.City AS Field3 
FROM (
    SELECT P.PersonID AS PersonID, P.DisplayName AS DisplayName FROM @Person P
    UNION
    SELECT LP.LostPersonID AS PersonID, LP.DisplayName AS DisplayName FROM @LostPersons LP) AS P        
LEFT OUTER JOIN @PersonDetail PD ON P.PersonID = PD.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN @PersonGeoInfo PGI ON PD.PersonID = PGI.PersonID
```